# Authentication in UWP by own .NET API. How to make it?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, uwp

I have problem with authentication in UWP. I created a simple API in .NET and have there a database with information about the Users. I can read this data in my UWP by json, but my authentication at now looks like that: data what I putting is checking in database and when it's correct the User is logged in. Then he goes to the next Frame. My question is: how to remember and check who is logged in (make something like a session) in others frames? Becouse at now, I have to pass all of the info about user by the object sender.

Answer (score 0):

To check, which user is logged in, you can do either

1. Make an update on a regular time interval (from the UWP app to the API), so you know that the user is still active or
2. Send a `logout`-request, when the user exits the application.

I would recommend the second option. If you consider it as well, have a look at the [App Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn765019.aspx) (official documentation with examples, you are interested in the "save state, when exiting the application")

If I understood you wrong and you just want to know, if the user is logged in locally, consider the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) in order to save the state and call it every time you need it.

Comment: I trying make a mobile app in UWP. And at now I dont know how to create the authentication. But the auth have to be from database not from local settings. I have info in DB about users. Normally in web app we have something like session where app know who is logged in and then we can show all info concering our user. At now I can connect to my DB. Read info in Json format and had made loop "if" on input field, but how to remember that which user is logged in?
I heard that can make token(?) on DB and on every Frame in UWP check who is logged in by this individual token. Is it a good way?